# Unable to install the gradle for android studio 3.0

Tags: android-studio, gradle, kotlin

I have started learning kotlin language and installed Android Studio canary build 3. Because i have a slow internet my Gradle build always fails.. then i downloaded the grade 4.0 milestone file ( got the link from Gradle wrapper properties. Tried replacing that link with the location of file on hard disk . But showing null point exception . Please help me out. I have a dam slow internet.

downloaded the file from here
`https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-milestone-1-all.zip`

```
`distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=E:\dwnld\gradle-4.0-milestone-1-all.zip`
```

this is the error shown

`

```
Error:java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.GradleInstallationManager.getWrappedGradleHome(GradleInstallationManager.java:554)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.GradleInstallationManager.getGradleHome(GradleInstallationManager.java:209)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.GradleInstallationManager.doGetGradleHome(GradleInstallationManager.java:194)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.GradleInstallationManager.getGradleHome(GradleInstallationManager.java:127)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleManager.lambda$getExecutionSettingsProvider$2(GradleManager.java:141)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.getExecutionSettings(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:718)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.ExternalSystemFacadeManager.prepare(ExternalSystemFacadeManager.java:219)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.ExternalSystemFacadeManager.doGetFacade(ExternalSystemFacadeManager.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.ExternalSystemFacadeManager.doInvoke(ExternalSystemFacadeManager.java:133)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.ExternalSystemFacadeManager$MyHandler.invoke(ExternalSystemFacadeManager.java:270)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.getResolver(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:139)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:125)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:388)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:445)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
`
```

Comment: I don't have an answer but I have a suggestion: delete the `.gradle` directory in your home directory. That's where the dependency cache is, so clearing it out may eliminate the corrupt file.

Comment: It is downloading the file again

Comment: Yep, it'll download a lot of files. Most of them will be under 100k though. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it .... First i extracted the gradle zip file to a folder(any) . Then gone to settings>build,execution,deployment>gradle then selected use local gradle distribution and selected the folder where i extracted the zip then applied.. it downloaded smome small files. Now its done